# Take console input and sort it from highest to lowest

Tags: c#, list, sorting

As the title say, I want to take inputs from the user via the console and use a list or array to sort them, then output the list.

Basically, the list is to have three variables, one string and two integers

(example:
infexis, 20, 19
john, 24, 3
jane, 17, 28

and the list should be output in the same format, though just sorted based on the first number, so john would be first, then infexis, then jane. the name and second number doesnt matter in the sorting.)

I'm really new to c#, and I'm wondering how to take user input and add it to a list with no specified amount of variables, (so the list can take 2 entries, or 12, not just a specified number.)
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest you introduction of class instead of string array in which you'll store user's input.

Example:

```
public class Person 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int FirstNumber { get; set; }
  public int SecondNumber { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
  //list of persons
  List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

  //Your piece of business logic ...

  //Creating person object

  var person = new Person();
  person.Name = Console.ReadLine();
  person.FirstNumber = Console.ReadLine();
  person.SecondNumber = Console.ReadLine();
  people.Add(person);

  //order by FirstNumber (needed to add: System.Linq namespace)
  var orderedPeople = people.OrderBy(p => p.FirstNumber);

  //output
  foreach(var p in orderedPeople)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", p.Name, p.FirstNumber, p.SecondNumber));
  }
}
```

Note: I didn't test this code, so you can expect some compile time bugs, but you can get broader way how to handle your problem easier.

Also, you can expand your class to meet additional requirement, like some other (optional) properties (i.e. user inputs)

Comment: I up-voted... But wanted to point out the the plural of person is people. I know it's a nitpick, but would drive me crazy if I saw in code I was working on :)